# Using PWA in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

How can I use PWA in ReactJS?

I'm using CRA (Creat-React-App), I remarked that I have already a /src/RegisterServiceWorker.js but I don't know if it is the correct file that I should use to build a PWA.

**This is RegisterServiceWorker.js**

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);
      } else {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

**The manifest.json:**

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Fatboar",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }, {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#2F3BA2",
  "background_color": "#3E4EB8"
}
```

According to some tutorials, I saw this piece of code that should be added to index.html but I'm not sure:

```
 <script>

// fichier : /script.js

if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  // On essaye d'enregistrer le service
  // worker
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register("/service-worker.js")
    .then(registration => {
      // Le Service Worker a fini d'être
      // téléchargé.
      console.log(
        "App: Téléchargement fini."
      );

      // (1) A chaque fois qu'il y a une
      // mise à jour des Service Workers
      registration.addEventListener(
        "updatefound",
        () => {
          // (1) On récupère le Service
          // Worker en cours
          // d'installation
          const newWorker =
            registration.installing;
          // `registration` a aussi
          // les clés `active` et 
          // `waiting` qui permettent
          // de récupérer les Service
          // Workers correspondant

          // (2) A chaque fois que le
          // Service Worker en cours
          // d'installation change
          // de statut
          newWorker.addEventListener(
            "statechange",
            () => {
              // (2) On affiche son
              // nouveau statut
              console.log(
                "App: Nouvel état :",
                newWorker.state
              );
            }
          );
        }
      );
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Il y a eu un problème
      console.error(
        "App: Crash de Service Worker",
        err
      );
    });
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't just use the serviceWorker that is shipped with CRA?

Comment: yes, and how about manifest.js, is it correct ? is there anything else to add ?

Comment: Look at this [checklist](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/checklist)

Comment: is it necessary to be in a production mode ?